# SwiftUI Issues with sheet modifier

Tags: swiftui

I have an initial view in my app that needs to open some modal views. The data I'm working with is form Core Data and I'm populating the list view with the `@FetchedRequest` property wrapper. The UI I'm trying to make is similar to the way you create and edit Lists in the Reminders app in iOS 13.

- Add record - Allow the user to create a new List (child objects are later) at any time.
- Edit record - Toggle the List view into Edit mode, tap an edit button on a row to open a modal to edit the record.

Both of these are *sort of* working now but there are some issues.

1. When I close the Add modal, *sometimes* I can't tap on the Edit button in the top right of the view. Nothing will happen at all when tapping. I tried attaching print state statement and doesn't get called. This happens most of the time, but not always.
2. When I edit a record using the process described above, when tap Cancel or Done to close this modal it will close. But after this point I cannot use this feature. If I try to open another edit model, it will open, but the data I pass to it is never displayed in the field.

I separated these into two views and sheets because I was having a lot of issues when I had them combined into a single view and sheet.

**Update:** Issue 1 was addressed by moving both .sheet modifiers outside of the NavigationView and attaching them to some hidden objects, as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57632426/11510425) answer.

As for issues 2, I spent some time this evening trying a few different things and I think I can see what the problem is. When the Edit modal is *re-opened* after the initial use, it is going through any sort of init process. No initialization is called, and even `onAppear()` attached to a view is not being called. In this case, the @State variable that the text field uses is never populated with the value from the record, because the text field code is not called again. I have no idea how to deal with this though. In any other environment I would just delete the instance and make a new one, but I don't know how to remove the cached instance of the Edit view created by the modal.

**Update:** as of 2019.08.27 the second issue was fixed with iOS 13.1. I didn't even have to recompile to see the fix.

### List view

*Updated to move the sheets outside of the NavigationView*

```
import SwiftUI

struct TimelineListView: View {

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext

    @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: Timeline.allTimelinesFetchRequest()) var timelines: FetchedResults<Timeline>

    @State var listViewEditMode: EditMode = .inactive

    @State var openModalSheetAdd = false

    @State var openModalSheetEdit = false
    @State var timelineToEdit: Timeline?

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
                NavigationView {
                    VStack {

                        List(self.timelines) { timeline in

                            NavigationLink(destination: TimelineDetailView(timeline: timeline)) {

                                HStack{
                                    Text(timeline.name ?? "Unnamed List")
                                    if (self.listViewEditMode == .active) {
                                        Spacer()
                                        Image(systemName: "info.circle")
                                            .onTapGesture {
                                                self.timelineToEdit = timeline
                                                self.listViewEditMode = .inactive
                                                self.openModalSheetEdit = true
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                            } //  End Navigation Link

                        } // End List

                        HStack {
                            Spacer()
                            Button("Add List") {
                                self.openModalSheetAdd = true
                            }.padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 10, trailing: 20))
                        }
                    }

                    .navigationBarTitle(Text("Lists"), displayMode: .inline)
                    .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())

                        .environment(\.editMode, self.$listViewEditMode)

                }// End Navigation View

            // Edit modal
            Text("").hidden()
                .sheet(isPresented: $openModalSheetEdit,
                       onDismiss: {
                        self.openModalSheetEdit = false
                },
                       content: {
                        TimelineEditView(timeline: self.timelineToEdit, onDismiss: {
                            self.openModalSheetEdit = false // this is here because sometimes onDismiss is not called.
                        })
                            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, self.managedObjectContext)
                })

            // Add modal
            Text("").hidden()
                .sheet(isPresented: $openModalSheetAdd,
                       onDismiss: {
                        self.openModalSheetAdd = false
                },
                       content: {
                        TimelineAddView(onDismiss: {
                            self.openModalSheetAdd = false // this is here because sometimes onDismiss is not called.
                        })
                            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, self.managedObjectContext)
                })
        }

    }
}
```

### Add record view

```
struct TimelineAddView: View {

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    @State private var nameEdit: String = ""


    // This closure is here to call when we dismiss the modal because onDismiss is not always called
    var onDismiss: () -> ()

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            HStack {

                Button(action: ({
                    self.nameEdit = ""
                    self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    self.onDismiss()
                })) {
                    Text("Cancel")
                }
                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 10, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))

                Spacer()

                Button(action: ({
                    let newTimeline = Timeline(context: self.managedObjectContext)
                    newTimeline.name = self.nameEdit
                    self.nameEdit = ""
                    do {
                        try self.managedObjectContext.save()
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                    self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    self.onDismiss()
                })) {
                    Text("Done")
                }
                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 10))
            }

            TextField("Data to edit", text: self.$nameEdit)
                .shadow(color: .secondary, radius: 1, x: 0, y: 0)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                .onAppear {
                    self.nameEdit = ""
            }.padding()
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

### Edit record view

```
struct TimelineEditView: View {

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    @State private var nameEdit = ""
    var timeline : Timeline?

    // This closure is here to call when we dismiss the modal because onDismiss is not always called
    var onDismiss: () -> ()

    var body: some View {

        return VStack {
            HStack {
                Button(action: ({
                    // Dismiss the modal sheet
                    self.nameEdit = ""
                    self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    self.onDismiss()
                })) {
                    Text("Cancel")
                }
                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 10, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))

                Spacer()
                Button(action: ({

                    self.timeline?.name = self.nameEdit

                    do {
                        try self.managedObjectContext.save()
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }

                    // Dismiss the modal sheet
                    self.nameEdit = ""
                    self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    self.onDismiss()
                })) {
                    Text("Done")
                }
                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 10))
            }

            TextField("Data to edit", text: self.$nameEdit)
                .shadow(color: .secondary, radius: 1, x: 0, y: 0)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                .onAppear {
                    self.nameEdit = self.timeline?.name ?? ""
            }.padding()
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't have time to review your code yet, but to debug "untouchable" buttons, I found adding borders on every view, even container views, can help you see surprising weird effects. I have seen some views occupying spaces they shouldn't and prevent tap gestures from ever occurring. Another debug option, use .zIndex(1000) on the untappable button.

Comment: Yeah I tried something like that. The issue is that the Edit butt just stops responding. If I navigate to another view and back it will work again. Something if I just scroll around for a but it will start working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.sheet` being embedded inside a `List` does only open once is a known bug and I hope they fix it. Until then you have to move `.sheet` outside of any `List`.

But since the `.sheet` is not inside a `List` but inside a `NavigationView`, it might a good idea to try to move the `.sheet` outside of it.

But do not attach two `.sheet` two the same View, but add them the following way instead:

```swift
VStack{
    NavigationView{ ... }
    Text("").hidden().sheet(...)
    Text("").hidden().sheet(...)
}
```

Comment: In my code above `.sheet` is outside of the list. Also, I keep hearing people say this is a "known" issue or bug but I can't find mention of this in the known issues in Xcode or iOS betas. Can you point me to where this "known" issue is?

Comment: @radicalappdev have you tried to move your first sheet outside the NavigationView? anyway a lot of use (and you too) noticed that there are something bugged or strange in swiftUI navigation

Comment: @radicalappdev were you able to fix it? The `known` comes from observing bugs on here to learn the technology. The least issues I encountered here are found in Release Notes. They probably don't want to unsettle new _SwiftUI_ users with problems only arriving in more complex scenarios. :-)

Comment: The bug is actually having a sheet inside a ScrollView but a List has that by default. As you are passing data to your sheet the sheet(item:...) may be more appropriate.

Comment: I attached the two sheets to `Text()` views as you described. This solved issue one in my post. Using the Add modal no longer interferes with the Edit modal. However, issue two is still happening. If I open the Edit modal, edit a record and tap done, when I reopen *any* Edit modal on the list it is not populated with data. The Core Data is being passed to the struct, and I can even overwrite it, but the code that populates the field with initial value is not running.

Comment: I updated my post above to reflect that this solved the first issues. I also added some additional information about the second issue and what I think might be happening.

Comment: One more update: as of iOS 13.1 the second issue was fixed.

Comment: @Fabian can you explain how to move the sheet outside the list? I am not entirely sure how to do that. Can you also go see my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60662263/issue-with-swiftui-listview-when-sheet-is-presented-and-then-dismissed , the list view gets blanked out when the sheet is presented, so when I dismiss it the list view is empty!?

Comment: @Learn2Code Outside the list just means using a vstack with the first item the list end the following items being hidden text fields having .sheets() attached. Or (if the second bug is fixed) attached to the list instead of being attached to views inside of the list-view. Hope that helps. Other than that I've no idea what the problem could be

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with `ScrollView`.
The `sheet` need to be add out of the `ScrollView` to be sure we can open more than once.

```
ScrollView {
    [...]
}.sheet([...])
```

It's really not practical if you extract your views into another views like for a DatePicker for exemple.